# What is this 2x2 white brick in the shape of a figure driving a go kart?

Tags: minifigure-identification

I have a 2x4 white Lego brick in the shape of a figure driving a go kart. It has a stalk to accommodate a head with Lego embossed on it. There is no serial number except for a 4 stamped underneath. Does anyone know what this brick is and what set it's from?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 6):

Based on your description, i think you have

[x351 - Brick, Modified 2 x 2 Racer Driver No Head](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x351&colorID=1&in=A)

[image]

This comes from:

[4593-1: Zero Hurricane and Red Blizzard](https://brickset.com/sets/4593-1/Zero-Hurricane-and-Red-Blizzard)